# SwiftUI - items of cell disappering

Tags: swiftui

You can copy this completely to a playground to reproduce. When you start it the preview looks good, but when you start scrolling up and down, items (HStack) disappears. I have no idea why... Is this an Apple bug or what I'm misunderstanding?

```
  //: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct Cell : View {

    var country: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("OMG").onAppear() { print ("OMG") }
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack() {
                    Text(country)

                }.background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))//.frame(height: 195)
            }.background(Rectangle().fill(Color.orange))//.frame(height: 205)

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var countries = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        UITableView.appearance().showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    }

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader() { geometry in
            VStack() {
                Text("Title")
                List(self.countries, id: \.self) { country in

                    Cell(country: country)

                }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 340)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Comment: did you tried the same code on a single view project instead of playground?

Comment: of course. there it was before (just more complicated) - i broke it down for playground and easy example.

Comment: Confirm reproducing not only in Playground, but also in Xcode Preview, Simulator and Catalyst

Answer (score 1):

By my investigation the problem is in using ScrollView inside List (maybe Apple's issue). As a workaround (or alternate) you can consider replacing List with ScrollView, like the following (body of your ContentView, and you can add manually Divider() where you'd like to have similar look):

```
var body: some View {

    GeometryReader() { geometry in
        VStack() {
            Text("Title")
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(self.countries, id: \.self) { country in
                    Cell(country: country)
                        .frame(height: 340)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```